# Make div 100px by 100px

Tags: html, css

How do I make these div's a specific size without using anything else then CSS and HTML?

As you can see if you try this code for yourself.
I have these boxes all in a row.
Id like to have more eventually as well, making almost a grid.

```css
body {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.blackcolor1 {
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline;
    min-height: 100px !important;
    min-width: 100px !important;
    max-height: 100px !important;
    max-width: 100px !important;
}
.border {
    margin: 100px;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <div class="blackcolor1"></div>
  <div class="blackcolor1"></div>
  <div class="blackcolor1"></div>
  <div class="blackcolor1"></div>
</div>
```

I have done every thing I know to do.
But my div's will not size to 100px X 100px.
I can only get them close.
I shoulden't have to put any content in theses for them to work.

Comment: Remove 'display: inline;'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign sizes to inline elements:

> This property does not apply to non-replaced inline elements. The content width of a non-replaced inline element's boxes is that of the rendered content within them (before any relative offset of children).
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-width

Replacing `display: inline` with `display: inline-block` will give you the intended sizing, while allowing the elements to exist on the same line.

Note that padding adds to the box size, unless you use `box-sizing: border-box`

```css
body {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.blackcolor1 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 100px !important;
    min-width: 100px !important;
    max-height: 100px !important;
    max-width: 100px !important;
}
.border {
    margin: 100px;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <div class="blackcolor1"></div>
  <div class="blackcolor1"></div>
  <div class="blackcolor1"></div>
  <div class="blackcolor1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to set the display attribute to be `inline-block` and not `inline`.  `inline` alone makes the `div` act the same as a `span`, whereas `inline-block` lets you specify width and height, but also be in-line with the rest of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `display:inline` with `float:left;`

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hq5xpsut/)